# Submenu not showing on hover - jQuery

Tags: jquery, nav, submenu

https://codepen.io/grantsmith/pen/YQweRb

I am trying to get my branded header menu, sub menu to appear upon hover. The code is pretty long, hence the code pen.

I’m targeting any 'a' in the menu that has children, and toggle the .nav-dropdown class.

Perhaps this is wrong way to go about this, open to suggestions. This is bound to be a jQuery issue as I'm pretty new to it.

```
(function($) {
$(function() {
$('nav ul li > a:not(:only-child)').click(function(e) {
  $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').toggle();
  $('.nav-dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$('html').click(function() {
  $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
});
});
document.querySelector('#nav-toggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
this.classList.toggle('active');
});
$('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
$('nav ul').toggle();
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: you have bound the event to your click which is probably why it is not showing on hover

Comment: Yes I see that now, however, doesn't work when I click either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KqVovo

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('nav>ul>li').mouseenter(function(e) {
      $(this).children('.nav-dropdown').show();
    });
    $('nav>ul>li').mouseleave(function(e) {
      $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This is much closer, however, sub menu doesn't stay open to be able to select the sub menu li's

Comment: Updated. Removed lots of stuff, changed to `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` for more control.

Comment: This is perfect, I'm still a complete novice when it comes to javascript :(. Thanks for your help

Comment: Just as an update, in case anyone else wishes to use the code. Although the sub menu showing issue is fixed. There is still an issue with the mobile toggle not showing/firing on hover?

Comment: What mobile toggle?  Keep in mind it's impossible to "hover" on mobile...